# How to get past wave 10 in the pumpkin moon?

Tags: terraria

I need to beat the pumpkin moon to get the bat scepter and horseman's blade. i get stuck on mourning woods mostly. pumpkings are easy.

- **Armor:** Beetle armor with the shell variant
- **Accessories:**

  - Obsidian sheild(Warding)
  - Fire gauntlet (Wild)
  - Warrior emblem (Violent)
  - Hover board (Warding)
  - Destroyer Emblem (Wild)
  - star veil (Warding)
- **Weapons:**

  - legendary terra blade
  - superior vampire knives

My arena has 172 spiky ball traps 32 flame traps 23 spear traps and a heart lantern and campfire. All rigged to a one second timer. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it not work?

Comment: No :( max i get to is wave 8

Comment: In general with Melee, I believe you usually make all of your accessories Menacing (+4 Damage).  More so with the Vampire knives, since the healing effect is based on the damage they do.  But with your beetle armor and the menacing accessories and the vampire knives, I should think you could get to the last waves.  Use all the healing articles you can, heart lanterns, campfires, heart and star statues, and even honey pits if you have to. (I don't like honey pits for melee bosses, but you might.)  Oh, and try a flask of ichor, if you can, as it reduces their defense.

Comment: Does golden shower give a different debuff to Flask of Ichor? You could use both to debuff them and then strike with your vampire knives.

Comment: @CrabtasticGoat, no the ichor debuff from the flask does not stack with golden shower.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.

Terra Blade is actually not that good on the pumpkin moon. Too many enemies. Instead, use something that can get like 10-20 at once like the Shadowbeam Staff (if your arena has a roof).

Get an Ankh Shield, those are really good.

Use Cholorophyte arrows, they bounce and do bad stuff to all the enemies.